# .htaccess redirect https to http except one page along with www to non-www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

on one of my domain i am using htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which redirect all https to http as well as www to non-www domain.

Now, i want secure.php page to use https protocol instead of http protocol also with redirection of www to non-www.

i can use below lines to acheive this...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/secure\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/secure\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

in my first htaccess if user access https://www.example.com then in redirects to http://example.com in single redirect.

after modification to secure secure.php page, on second htaccess consider case if user access http://www.example.com/secure.php ->redirects to http://example.com/secure.php -> redirect to https://example.com/secure.php
here i get two redirects.

Pls suggest how can i club my criteria like in my first htaccess using [OR], so than in all cases it uses atmost one redirect to reach final page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secure\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(secure\.php.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```